# Can foxes move their ears independently?

Tags: zoology, ethology, hearing

I've read that dogs can do move their ears independently, i.e., point one ear in the direction of a sound without having to point the other one at the same time. Is this a common trait with other canids, such as foxes? Can most eared mammals do this, with humans being an exception (except for a few exceptional humans)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they can. Here are a couple pics I found of foxes moving their ears independently:

[image]

[image]

This is something all canids can do [(1)](http://www.responsibledog.net/canine_senses.html)[(2)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0060113219) Btw, I can move my ears independantly. It's all in the finding the right muscles.

Comment: How can you tell from a still photo that only one ear is moving?

Comment: @daniel Easy - because it is swiveled from it's natural position. Red foxes will point both ears at one thing if paying it full attention. The foxes pictured were pointing both ears in different directions, because apparently two things were catching it's attention.

Comment: Not easy for me. Your reference (1) does not support your point directly and  reference (2) is to a book with no page number. Can you please find a reference that directly supports the point?